# looping through user input with an if condition

Tags: python, loops, input

Hi I want to loop through this input if balance does not match the sum of book balances(pp, bfair, sky, freds wh)

```
while True:
        try:
            balance = float(raw_input('Balance:'))
            print balance
        except ValueError:
            print"That's not a number"
            continue
        else:
            break
while True:
        try:
            bfair_balance = float(raw_input('bfair:'))
            print bfair_balance
        except ValueError:
            print"That's not a number"
            continue
        else:
            break
while True:
        try:
            wh_balance = float(raw_input('wh:'))
            print wh_balance
        except ValueError:
            print"That's not a number"
            continue
        else:
            break
while True:
        try:
            freds_balance = float(raw_input('freds:'))
            print freds_balance
        except ValueError:
            print"That's not a number"
            continue
        else:
            break
while True:
        try:
            sky_balance = float(raw_input('sky:'))
            print sky_balance
        except ValueError:
            print"That's not a number"
            continue
        else:
            break
while True:
        try:
            pp_balance = float(raw_input('pp:'))
            print pp_balance
        except ValueError:
            print "That's not a number"
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Do i put this all in another while loop with the if statements meeting the conditions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

And consider using functions to avoid repetitions in your code:

```
def ask_float(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            x = float(raw_input(msg))
            print x
            return x
        except ValueError:
            print "That's not a number"
            continue


while True:
    balance = ask_float('Balance:')
    bfair_balance = ask_float('bfair:')
    wh_balance = ask_float('wh:')
    freds_balance = ask_float('freds:')
    sky_balance = ask_float('sky:')
    pp_balance = ask_float('pp:')
    balance_sum = pp_balance + bfair_balance + sky_balance + freds_balance + wh_balance
    if balance == balance_sum:
        # balance is correct -> stop the loop
        break
    else:
        print("put a nice error message here")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was going to ask how to condense that code as im sure there was a way and you already did it! Thanks again, that was a big help!